# it opens new tab when we click on Print button

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

i am login in to application ,after that i have to fill data in some fields ,after that i have to click on the print toolbar button ,when i click print button it is opening new tab with unique descriptor (i.e it changes every time when we click print).so i need to navigate to that tab.
i have tried some code:
here is my code

```
enter code here`await t .click(Selector('# ddlpreBankAcc - pi');
```

await t. click(Selector('# dllprepredistributionType');
await t. typeText(Selector('#dateofevent').nth(1), d).setTestSpeed(0.6)
await t. click(Selector('#btnPrePrint');`

After this line it is opening new tab in chrome .
how to write code for that .
but in that new tab descriptor is unique descriptor.

Comment: Could you please share a small project example where the issue is reproducible?
This will allow me to determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.